# Integrating a Modified Bessel function of the second kind with a singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, bessel-functions, singularity

Does someone know how to handle the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{K_0\!\left(\lvert \tau \rvert \sqrt{q^2 \alpha ^2}\right)}{q^2}\cos (q x)\,\mathrm{d}q $$

$\alpha$ is a real number and $\tau$ is imaginary time. We have two problems at $q=0$, namely: the singularity originating from $\frac{1}{q^2}$ and the Modified Bessel function of the second kind blows up in the other direction. The latter behaviour is dominant. I was considering making the case that the argument of the Bessel function is small, thus claiming $K_0\!\left(\lvert \tau \rvert \sqrt{q^2 \alpha ^2}\right) \approx \log\left(\lvert \tau \rvert \sqrt{q^2 \alpha ^2}\right)$. But in the end, I'm left with the same problems as before. Does anyone have an idea how to approach this?

Kind regards,
Roeland

Comment: What is the context for this integral appearing? Is it a portion of a multiple integral?

Comment: It diverges owing to the integrand's behavior at $q=0$.

Comment: Mathematica gives the conditional result $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(q x) K_0\left(|\tau| \sqrt{q^2 \alpha^2}\right)}{q^2} \, dq=\pi  \left(\sqrt{\alpha^2 \tau \tau^*+x^2}-x \sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{|\alpha \tau| }\right)\right)$$ which is valid for $$\tau \neq 0\land |\alpha  \tau| \geq |\Im(x)|.$$

Comment: Thank you very much Steven!

Comment: @StevenClark How does that integral converge??

Comment: @MarkViola Perhaps the answer I posted below provides some insight.

Comment: @StevenClark Actually, it does not.  The integrand is not integrable due to the singularity at $q=0$.  Perhaps there is a distributional interpretaton here??

Comment: @MarkViola Mathematica gives distributional results when evaluating integrals with the MellinTransform and FourierTransform functions for example, but in these cases evaluating the integral with the Integrate function typically gives a result indicating the integral doesn't converge. In this particular case Mathematica essentially gives the same result using the Integrate function even independent of whether the Cauchy Principal value option is used. so perhaps the integral somehow converges in a non-distributional sense under the conditions specified.

Comment: Hi Steven.  I don't see how this integral converges.  Look at the small argument approximation of the modified Bessel function and look at the $1/q^2$ term.  Simply put, $\log(|x|)/x^2$ is not integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica gives the conditional result

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(q x) K_0\left(|\tau| \sqrt{q^2 \alpha^2}\right)}{q^2} \, dq=\pi  \left(\sqrt{\alpha^2 \tau \tau^*+x^2}-x \sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{|\alpha \tau| }\right)\right)\tag{1}$$

which is valid for $\tau \neq 0\land |\alpha  \tau| \geq |\Im(x)|$.

---

Note the integrand is an even function of $q$ and Mathematica gives the same result for

$$2 \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(q x) K_0\left(|\tau|\, \sqrt{q^2 \alpha^2}\right)}{q^2} \, dq=\pi \left(\sqrt{\alpha^2 \tau \tau^*+x^2}-x \sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{|\alpha \tau|}\right)\right)\tag{2}$$

which is again valid for $\tau \neq 0\land | \alpha \tau| \geq |\Im(x)|$.

---

I believe formula (2) above is equivalent to

$$2\, \mathcal{M}_q\left[K_0\left(|\tau|\, \sqrt{q^2 \alpha^2}\right) \cos(q x)\right](-1)=\pi x \left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^2}{x^2}} \sqrt{\frac{x^2 \left(\frac{\alpha^2 |\tau|^2}{x^2}+1\right)}{\alpha^2}}-\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{|\tau| \sqrt{\frac{\alpha^2}{x^2}}}\right)\right)\tag{3}$$

where

$$\mathcal{M}_q[f(q)](s)=\int_0^{\infty } f(q)\, q^{s-1} \, dq\tag{4}$$

is the Mellin transform of $f(q)$.

---

See [WolframAlpha evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2+MellinTransform%5B+++BesselK%5B0%2C+Abs%5B%5C%5BTau%5D%5D+Sqrt%5Bq%5E2+%5C%5BAlpha%5D%5E2%5D%5D+Cos%5Bq+x%5D%2C+q%2C+-1%5D) of formula (3) above.

---

I believe formula (2) above is also equivalent to the Mathematica evaluation

$$2 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\, \text{FourierCosTransform}\left[\frac{K_0\left(|\tau|  \sqrt{q^2 \alpha^2}\right)}{q^2},q,x\right]=\pi  \left(\sqrt{\alpha^2 \tau \tau^*+x^2}-x \sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{|\alpha \tau|}\right)\right),\quad\tau\neq 0\tag{5}$$

where

$$\text{FourierCosTransform}[f(q),q,x]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(q)\, \cos(x q) \, dq\tag{6}$$